# Typehead.js strange behaviour remotely - sometimes not showing result

Tags: javascript, bloodhound, typehead

I have a lot of strange things happen using latest typehead (typeahead.js 0.11.1) as typeheadbundle

First of all I'm using typeahead.bundle.min.js v0.11.1 remotely with 2 datasets. Problem is server is responding correctly, but typehead just doesn't care, and says nothing found.

The strange thing that sometimes typehead displays results correctly, sometimes only one dataset and sometimes it displaying nothing. But the server gives results!

**Update**

I found out that typehead has a bug in latest stable version. Here is fixed https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show some more care: typhead, typeahead, typeheadbundle, typehead.js. What's the difference between those four?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typehead has bug in latest stable version :)

I didn't believe it.

Untill found some good guys made a fork and fixed it
https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js

I though if this is maintained by twitter - and I'm using latest stable version - probably I do something wrong, but even big name fails :(

Answer (score 0):

I get you.

When I first started to use [`typehead`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), I also got some error, but leter on I have found that, it was my fault.

There is some configuration needed in using [`typehead.js`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). So, I have created a complete example of using [`typehead.js`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) using local data and using server data (AJAX).

You can check the [this **Github Repo**](https://github.com/abrarjahin/twitter-typehead).

---

### Re-

For your understanding, I am giving a small demo in here (no CSS)-

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs)
{
 return function findMatches(q, cb)
 {
  var matches, substrRegex;

  // an array that will be populated with substring matches
  matches = [];

  // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
  substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

  // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
  // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
  $.each(strs, function(i, str)
  {
   if (substrRegex.test(str))
   {
    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
    matches.push({ value: str });
   }
  });

  cb(matches);
 };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#typehead_example').typeahead(
      {
       hint:  true,
       highlight: true,
       minLength: 1
      },
      {
       name:  'states',
       displayKey: 'value',
       source:  substringMatcher(states)
      }
     );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.0.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<input id="typehead_example" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
```

Complete example is given in [this **Github Repo**](https://github.com/abrarjahin/twitter-typehead).